# pass view from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity, graph

I'm trying to pass a view from one activity to another activity.

In my 1st activity, `onButtonClick`, I'm navigating to another activity by using `Intent`.

I've written this line `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in 1st activity and also declared a `graphView`.

Now the problem is, I want to populate the `graphView` in the second activity but it's reference i.e. `mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);` is present in 1st activity.

So how can I acess `mySimpleXYPlot` in 2nd activity?

if I use

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);
```

in 2nd activity, whole layout gets restarted which I don't want to happen :(

**ANY HELP WILL BE APPRICIATED !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the same xml in the second content view. If you have to use a specific part of your layout in more then one view put it in an separate xml and include it.

Comment: put the view elements you want to use in a separate xml called plotviews.xml or something similar and then put <layout include="@layout/plotviews" /> in your content views where you want to have the plot view. This way you can get the view by findViewById in both activities.

Comment: what do you mean by "rest of the layout is not working" . remember that all clickListner and other handlers need to be set again after call setContentView() .

Comment: sorry but I didn't got that very clearly. Do I need to use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in both activities or just in 1st? If I don't write `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in 2nd activity I'm getting `nullPointerException`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question at first. I thought you want to have a second plotview in the second activity. You should work with startActivityForResult http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html, pack the data you want to plot as parcable or serializable in the bundle and process it in the activity which holds the plot view.

Comment: I can't get an example where parcel is used to pack the view. Is it like that ,It can pack int,string,etc. but not view?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use same instance that declare as static with public so you can used in another class or activity also

Edit...

In Activity 1st do like this way

```
public class MyActivity1 extends Activity{
    public static XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

    public onCreated(Bundle b){
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);
       // start you 2nd activity from button
    }
}
```

In Activity2 use this way

```
public class MyActivity2 extends Activity{
    private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;
    public onCreated(Bundle b){
       setContentView(R.layout.main); 
       mySimpleXYPlot = MyActivity2.mySimpleXYPlot;
       // use mySimpleXYPlot as per your requirement
    }
}
```

I am not sure this work perfectly or not but try this way and say what happen with this

**Edit2**

don't add your component into the xml layout file add at oncreate time

my layout file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/main_linear"
   >
  <Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:text="Click" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my first activity

```
    public static EditText edittext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    //edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear);

    edittext = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    edittext.setId(1);
    edittext.setText("text change");
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
            ll.removeView(edittext);
            startActivity(new Intent(TestLinear.this,TestClass.class));
        }
    });
    ll.addView(edittext);
}
```

you need to remove first that component from the layout in which you have added as child

```
    private static EditText edittext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear);
    getEdit();
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("test", edittext.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    ll.addView(edittext);
}
static void  getEdit(){
    edittext = TestLinear.edittext;
}
```

I know this not perfect way. Another way is you can store it's value in custom class like setter/getter and used in activity

Comment: in 2nd activity layout is main or different layout you used please update your question what you have tried it upto

Comment: let me explain. I've created the whole layout in main.xml. I'm setting the content to this layout in 1st activity. Now I want to plot points on graph with two arrays. on buttonClick, I pass these two arrays to 2nd activity and try to display that on graph. But doing so, whole layout is getting disturbed. I want to **PASS** mySimpleXYPlot created in _1st activity_ and not **CREATE** it again in _2nd activity_

Comment: I have done one example but it's too much complex check edit2

Comment: When I click on button and navigate to another activity, graph is displayed but all the onClickListeners and similar things can not be used. i.e. If I have certain functionality on some button click in activity 1 and then I'm navigating to 2nd activity, then functionality of that button is lost as onClickListener for that button is present in activity1 and not in activity2.