# Pass a layout from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I pass an exactly looking RelativeLayout from one activity to another. The result shoul look something like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYp45.jpg)

To explain:

I have a GridView which is populated from database using SimpleCursorAdapter and a partial layout.
Partial layout looks something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>    
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

When user clicks on a details button of an item, I woud like to pass that item's RelativeLayout to the DetailsActivity.

As I understand it [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159211/how-do-i-clone-a-view) is not posible and [inflating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573820/pass-view-from-one-activity-to-another) is not an option.

I coud pass every id, tag and text value and recreate a layout but I'm hopinbg there's an easier way.

Comment: add that layout to top of 2nd activity .you don't need to pass anything.after all it's the details activity so it will have those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a layout.

What you can do is

- use the same layout resource (defined in xml) in both the places.
- pass the data to be used in layout from one screen to other.